# C# consumption of C++ DLL function that exports an abstract class/interface?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interface

I have a DLL that has only one export function:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
{
   __declspec(dllexport) IRouter* CreateRouter(); 
}
#endif
```

The interface for IRouter is as follows:

```
class IRouter
{
public:
    virtual bool __stdcall DoSomething(LPCWSTR szCommand) = 0;
    // Call Release() from DLL client to free any memory associated with this object
    virtual bool __stdcall Release() = 0;
};
```

and I have a concrete class whose interface is as follows:

```
class CMyRouter : public IRouter
{
public:
    bool __stdcall DoSomething(LPCWSTR szCommand);
    bool __stdcall Release();
}
```

As you'd expect, the implementation for MyRouter class is included in the DLL.

The code for my single export function is as follows:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
{
    __declspec(dllexport) IRouter* CreateRouter()
    {
        return new CMyRouter;
    }
}
#endif  // __cplusplus
```

My question is: How can I access my IRouter derived object from a C# client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in C++/CLI (using aggregation, not inheritance).  For example, create a managed class in C++/CLI that corresponds to and holds a pointer to the C++ abstract class `IRouter`, and provides the few forwarding methods such as `` `DoSomething(string) ``.  You can then implement the rest of the managed logic in C#.

It is also possible, but not exactly aligned with your current formulation of the question, to consume the class using P/Invoke or COM.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  If I understand correctly, I'll need to write another C++/CLI DLL to act as an intermediary between my native C++ DLL and my C# client.  Do you know of an example of such a C++/CLI aggregation solution?  And you're right, I was planning to consume the class using P/Invoke.

Comment: @markiemooster - You will not need P/Invoke if you go with C++/CLI.  You simply need to create a C++/CLI project in Visual Studio and learn the basics of the language (for example, [here][1]) (You also received an answer by Nanhydrin that addresses the P/Invoke way, but it is extremely unusual and inconvenient to use P/Invoke with class methods.)

Comment: @markiemooster - I forgot to paste the link: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes]